# How to write a nested query?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have following table:

```
+-----+---+----+
|type | t |code|
+-----+---+----+
|    A| 25|  11|
|    A| 55|  42|
|    B| 88|  11|
|    A|114|  11|
|    B|220|  58|
|    B|520|  11|
+-----+---+----+
```

And what I want:

```
+-----+---+----+
|t1   | t2|code|
+-----+---+----+
|   25| 88|  11|
|  114|520|  11|
+-----+---+----+
```

There are two types of events A and B.
Event A is the start, Event B is the end.
I want to connect the start with the next end dependence of the code.

It's quite easy in SQL to do this:

```
SELECT a.t AS t1,  
   (SELECT b.t FROM events AS b WHERE a.code == b.code AND a.t < b.t LIMIT 1) AS t2, a.code AS code
FROM events AS a
```

But I have to problem to implement this in Spark because it looks like that this kind of nested query isn't supported...

I tried it with:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("events")
val sqlDF = spark.sql(/* SQL-query above */)
```

Error i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Accessing outer query column is not allowed in:
```

Do you have any other ideas to solve that problem?

Comment: _"because it looks like that this kind of nested query isn't supported"_ did you try to run it? Did you get any exception? If so, include it in your question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's quite easy in SQL to do this

And so is in Spark SQL, luckily.

```
val events = ...
scala> events.show
+----+---+----+
|type|  t|code|
+----+---+----+
|   A| 25|  11|
|   A| 55|  42|
|   B| 88|  11|
|   A|114|  11|
|   B|220|  58|
|   B|520|  11|
+----+---+----+

// assumed that t is int
scala> events.printSchema
root
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- t: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- code: integer (nullable = true)

val eventsA = events.
  where($"type" === "A").
  as("a")
val eventsB = events.
  where($"type" === "B").
  as("b")
val solution = eventsA.
  join(eventsB, "code").
  where($"a.t" < $"b.t").
  select($"a.t" as "t1", $"b.t" as "t2", $"a.code").
  orderBy($"t1".asc, $"t2".asc).
  dropDuplicates("t1", "code").
  orderBy($"t1".asc)
```

That should give you the requested output.

```
scala> solution.show
+---+---+----+
| t1| t2|code|
+---+---+----+
| 25| 88|  11|
|114|520|  11|
+---+---+----+
```